# Export PointCloud to CAD software

Tags: ros, cad, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is the best way to export a pointcloud topic to CAD software like AutoCAD or SolidWorks?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10977/export-pointcloud-to-cad-software/) by [patrick_hammer](https://answers.ros.org/users/465/patrick_hammer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 283 on 2011-08-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have a look at [this code](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/rgbdslam/html/graph__manager_8cpp_source.html#l00931). It saves a pcl::PointCloudpcl::PointXYZRGB to the ply format.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2011-08-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0